# Java array reading from a file

Tags: java, arrays, file

Say i have a file called "input.txt" that has a bunch of positive integers in it:

> 6
>  5
>  6
>  8
>  6
>  2
>  4

and so on....(one integer per line)

I want to read this file and make it into an array. The first integer (in this case 6) tells the number of indexes or elements in the array, so 6 spots. The other numbers fill in the array starting at 0. So at index 0, the number is 5, at index 1 the number is 6, and so on.

Can someone please show me how to read this file and make it into an array called A and return the integers in each index as n?

this is what i have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class inputFile {
    public static jobScheduleRecursive(int[] A, int i)
    {
        try
    {
        FileReader filereader = new FileReader("input.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
        String line = bufferedreader.readLine();
        //While we have read in a valid line
        while (line != null) {
            //Try to parse integer from the String line
            try {
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line));
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.err.println("Failed to parse integer from line:" + line);
                System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            line = bufferedreader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException filenotfoundexception)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
    catch(IOException ioexception)
    {
        System.out.println("File input error occured!");
        ioexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return A;
}
```

Comment: We're not going to do your work for you.  What have you tried?  Post your current code, and we can help you correct it.

Comment: homework?  what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

Step by step (I will let you fill in the actual code):

1. read the first integer (the `java.util.Scanner` can be used to read the next integer) into a variable (let's call it `numberOfInts`)
2. Create an array called `A` with `numberOfInts` elements
3. In a loop, counting from `0` to `numberOfInts - 1` (using index variable `i`):

   - read the next integer from the file
   - set `A[i]` to be that integer you just read

Here are some references:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html